# Google analytics social media hit - organic hit

Tags: php, html, wordpress, google-analytics

Traffic coming to my site via twitter appears as "social media" on google analytics page. I want to show them somehow as organic traffic. So I want it to look like this in google analytics. I saw those who did this, but I have no idea how I should do it. Does anyone know this method?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? "Organic" traffic has a specific definition. Traffic which comes from a search engine does not fit that definition. I can't really see why you would wish to fake your results. What benefit do you get from that?

Comment: I just wonder how it's done. Of course, I know very well that doing this will not get me high on google.

Answer (score 1):

In **Admin -> View -> Channel Settings -> Channel Grouping** you can edit the rules for a predefined channel or define a new channel, i.e.:

[image]